# InvalidCastException mapping Json string onto Guid property

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, guid, .net

Having theese POCOs:

```
public class UserRegistration
{
    [Required]
    public ApiKey ApiKey { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class ApiKey 
{
    [Required]
    public Guid AppKey { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and this Json:

```
{
    "apiKey": {
      "appKey": "D8B4DE20-5654-43B0-B3F6-FDA416087FDE"
    }
}
```

I'm getting an exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String'.
at System.Web.Http.ApiController.d__b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__0.MoveNext()
```

calling this an ASP.NET Web API controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put([FromBody]UserRegistration userRegistration)
{
}
```

If change property type form Guid to string, all works fine, but I want Guid. Is such scenario supported?

Comment: This should be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640463/json-net-exception-when-deserializing-an-array-of-guids

Comment: @EhsanUllah: Does it mean Guid is not supported and I need to accept string and then parse it manually?

Comment: The post linked above is talking about being unable to deserialize an array of guids directly - but you've got just this one guid on the object, right? Is the exception text complete btw? It's saying unable to cast Guid but it's not saying to which type - can you post the full message?

Comment: @JoannaTurban: Sorry, exception message turned out to be truncated. Fixed. Guid to String.

Comment: @EhsanUllah: actually it's supported pretty fine, see my own answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is not obviously following from the exception stack trace, problem was not in mapping but in validation attribute decoration:

```
[Required]
[StringLength(36)] // NO-NO!
public Guid AppKey { get; set; }
```